# Angular promise works intermittently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

My app makes a request for data that is returned in the form of a promise. I loop through and make 10 requests pushing the promises to an array and then `$q.all` the array. I `.then` update the model for ng-repeat and the data is displayed in the view.

All that works but when I click a button to run the operation again with new requests, the model is only updated if I wait about 5 seconds. If I click the button prior to that everything runs up until the point of updating the model

**From the Controller**

```
$scope.getPage = function(pageNum) {
  placesFact.getPage(pageNum).then(function(results){
    console.log('$scope.getPage fired', results); // This only fires if I wait about 5 seconds after previous run.
    $scope.details = results;
  });
};
```

**From the Factory**

```
 places.getPage = function(pageNum) {
  var promises = [];

  for(var i=0; i<pages[pageNum].length; i++) {
    promises.push(places.getPlace(pages[pageNum][i]));
  }
  console.log("places.getPage fired", promises); // This fired and changes the array
  return $q.all(promises);
};

places.getPlace = function(id) {
  var deferred = $q.defer(),
      request = {placeId: id};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  function callback(results, status){
    if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      return deferred.resolve(results);
    }
  }
  service.getDetails(request, callback);
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: What does it show on the network tab?

Comment: @ewahner nothing seems to be running a long time. Most things seems to be ending in a few ms's with a few in the 40-60ms range and a couple outliers in the 150-160 range

Comment: So you are saying that the network tab shows that the promises have all succeeded yet the console doesn't log the success?

Comment: Try changing `return deferred.resolve(results);` to just `deferred.resolve(results);`

Comment: When I look in network I see the calls being made to the PlacesService even though the console isn't logging the success (very odd, I'm pretty stumped). I tried that change but still no luck. Thanks though